# spring MVC forwarding request to another controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have few spring controllers all of these controller modelAttribtes are extended some commonForm(BaseForm). All common properties were in BaseForm and specific properties are in sub classes which acts as ModelAttributes for controllers.
Based on special condition I have scenarios to forward to another controller but while this forward is happening the request contains old data as well and giving double values to the parameters and failing the forwarded request.

Actually this code is copied from struts based project as part of migrating to spring MVC.

Please help me on this.

Thanks,

Syamala.

Comment: some code from the baseform, a subclass and controller method using the subclass would be useful

Comment: can you post your relevant code?